# What is the default image quality in a pypdf image's "replace" attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, pypdf

In the documentation of pypdf I can find the following about reducing image quality:

```
from pypdf import PdfReader, PdfWriter

reader = PdfReader("example.pdf")
writer = PdfWriter()

for page in reader.pages:
    writer.add_page(page)

for page in writer.pages:
    for img in page.images:
        img.replace(img.image, quality=80)

with open("out.pdf", "wb") as f:
    writer.write(f)
```

However, with respect to `img.replace(img.image, quality=80)` I cannot find what the default quality setting is. Is it percentage-wise, so it would be 100? That is to say, if I would use `quality=100` it would replace the image with the same image? Or is it something else entirely?

I've tried using `help(img.replace)`, `help(img.image.save)`, and `help(open(img.name, "wb").write)` but to no avail.

The reason I need this is because I want to know if it's relative or absolute, as I'd like for the user to give a "level" of compression.